# Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

El caso es que tengo un `ProgressDialog` dentro de una clase `AsyncTask` y el caso es que cuando esta se ejecuta, para realizar una conexion, la primera vez me sale el Progress correctamente, pero si vuelvo a realizar una busqueda (es de lo que se encarga el `Asynctask`) me salta el siguiente error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>               Process: com.xxxx.cccc, PID: 25502
>                                                                    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
>                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:765)
>                   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:356)
>                   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
>                   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:330)
>                   at com.xxxx.cccc.conexion.CRC.onPreExecute(CRC.java:79)
>                   at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:648)
>                   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:595)
>                   at com.xxxx.cccc.listas.LCNA$5.onClick(LCNA.java:127)
>                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
>                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
>                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Este es el codigo:

```
public class xxxx extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
...
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
...
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(contexto);
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Conectando con el servidor. Espere por favor...");
    progressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... values) {
...
    if (conectarServidor()) {
        publishProgress();

        transferenciaInformacion(); //Recibe información del Servidor y lo trata

        this.cancel(true);

    } else {
        publishProgress();
    }


    return "true";
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
progressDialog.cancel();


}

 @Override
protected void onCancelled(String s) {
progressDialog.cancel();
    super.onCancelled(s);
}

    @Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    /**
     * Condición de que no haya logrado conectarse con el servidor
     * En cuyo caso lanzará un AlertDialog advirtiéndolo
     * Si se ha logrado conectar no se lanzará el AlertDailog
     * Además lanzará un mensaje de Error dependiendo de si ha sido por error de conexión o porque se ha agotado el tiempo de espera de conexión
     */

    if (!isConectado && isTimeOut) {
        Handler handler = new Handler(contexto.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(contexto, "Error de conexión. No se pueden cargar los articulos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    } else if (!isConectado && isIOError) {
        Handler handler = new Handler(contexto.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(contexto, "Error de conexión. No se pueden cargar los articulos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}

...
```

La llamada al metodo:

```
XXXXX xxxx= new XXXXX(contexto);
xxxx.execute("","");
```

Esta esta situada en un boton que no se vuelve a clicar hasta que no se haya terminado todo el proceso que realiza el AsyncTask

El codigo que esta con XX o con caracteres raros es irrelevante, he quitado el codigo sobrante que es irrelevante para el caso.

Comment: Deberías poner el código donde creas, inicias y muestras el ProgressDialog además de la excepción para que podamos ver donde y porqué falla. Aquí tienes una guía para realizar preguntas de calidad de acuerdo a la política del sitio, [ask].

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta

Comment: El problema es obvio pero como resolverlo considero que necesitaría tu código, te sugiero leas lo que comentan Pablo yPikoh, es importante para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida y obtengas buenas respuestas.

Comment: He actualizado, ya tenéis el código.